# Only bold subscripts not superscripts

Tags: boldsymbol

If I have a mathematical symbol：[image]
, and I just want to bold the subscript regardless of the superscripts.
However, when I use code: `\boldsymbol{A_{a1}}^2`, the results is [image].
How can I get the right results instead of superscript far away.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
$\mathbf{A}_\mathbf{a1}^2$
or
$\bm{A}_{\bm{a1}}^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The second method you mention solves my problem.

Comment: @器和树木丛生 Welcome to the site.  If the answer is wholly satisfactory and the best of the possibly several offered, consider clicking the check mark to the left of such an answer.  This will signify to other readers that you have "accepted" one particular answer as the best.